# Check if value in column B exists in column A

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Using Power Query in Power BI, I need to check for each row of `MyTable` if the value in column `B` exists in column `A`.

If it does, then that value should be returned on a new column, then an empy field should be returned on that column.

This is the code I'm trying to enter into an if statement somehow:

```
Table.Contains(MyTable,[B],[A])
```

Which is returing a cyclical reference error.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is just to merge the table on itself

Home..Merge Queries ... and merge Table1 to Table1(Current) and then click on ColumnB in top and ColumnA in bottom. Expand result using arrows atop new column and then only select [x] ColumnA.

Sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Column2"},Source,{"Column1"},"Source",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Source" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Source", {"Column1"}, {"Column1.1"})
in #"Expanded Source"
```

Comment: All joins in PQ use the "NestedJoin" function. This is definitely a very efficient and quick check, but could also cause issues depending on what data you have in columns A and B. If there are any duplicate values in column A, then it will create a duplicate row from expanding the join operation. If that is the case you would then instead of expanding the join results, you would want to add a custom column that checks if the result of the join is an empty table and keeps the value in B or returns blank.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you want these results, so I just put it in as an added column to a theoretical sample table.

Given this table:

[image]

And this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "C", each if List.Contains(Source[A], [B]) then [B] else null)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Gives this result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for helping, I get the error "Can't convert value .... to type List, Columns A and B are of type Text.

Comment: This solution works fine. It will give you that error if you wrote `[A]` instead of `Source[A]`. The latter is a list whereas the former is a cell value.

Comment: This exact code only works in the sample I showed here. I don't know what your data looks like so I couldn't say what you need to change there, but the "Source[A]" is a supposed to be a reference to a column in your table (that you are checking if the value in B exist in).